# How to update two identical fragments in Android

Tags: android

I am working with Fragments in Android. I have two identical fragments FragA and FragB. Since they are identical: I need a method that says if I am on FragA and a textView in FragA changed or updates the same textView should change/update in FragB. Can anyone help me with creating a method that takes data from FragA changed about a particular View and passes it to FragB to update its View.

I have tried using interfaces and ViewModel for communicating with fragments, but I can't seem to figure out how to update two identical fragments when let's say one of them changes.

Comment: Rather than trying to propagate changes from A->B or from B->A, make sure you only ever update them together. Maybe make a function in your Activity that updates both at the same time, or use ViewModel provided from your Activity and have both fragments listen to its LiveData

Comment: You can do that through their activity

Comment: Hi @BenP., I do like the idea of updating them together. How can I approach making a function in my Activity that updates both at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an easily approachable problem these days. With a `ViewModel` we can achieve this easily.

We can make a `ViewModel` where our `MutableLiveData` can live.

Our two (or more) fragments can observe the `LiveData` events and both update at the same time.

I could post some code but I really think this CodeLabs is exactly what you are looking for and can get you up to speed in just a few minutes.

[Android Lifecycle Aware Components Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/index.html)

Comment: Thats actually the best way of doing it following the actual mvvm pattern and using LiveData component.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with an external and awesome library, https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus . This is a hidden gem for easy fragment to fragment communication in android. The docs are pretty self explanatory.

Please note: if you are using eventbus please remember to register eventbus only in the fragments OR classes you will be using it in, you do not have register an eventbus even in the class from where you are posting the event, else it will be giving you a compile time error. Also DO Not forget to unregister the eventbus using `EventBus.getDefault().unRegister(this);` or `EventBus.getDefault().unregister(context);`
in order to prevent memory leaks

Comment: This may be good for simpler applications but in my experience, it doesn't scale well.

Comment: I have used it in an ongoing live project. Its a doctor booking and healthcare management sort of app. I havent had any problems with it as of yet. @RichardDapice can you list some of the things that might go wrong?

Comment: Too much to mention here, I would recommend looking into it further. It was born to solve a problem that has since been solved through much more efficient means. It ends up allowing code to be written poorly and multidirectional.